# Can a Panel nest another panel?

Tags: panel

How possible is to fold and unfold a panel on the TOOLS region that reveals other panels? like cascading panels: 
(panel) Geometry>>
        (subpanel1)GET>
        (subpanel2) CURVES>
        (subpanel3) MODIFY> (menu)> item menu1
                                     (submenu)> item1
                                     (submenu)> item2

How do I nest panels inside panels?
thanks.